# "MasterNotRunningException Failed to find any Kerberos tgt" when connecting to localhost standalone HBase without Kerberos with Java

Tags: java, hbase, kerberos

I've got a standalone HBase running on my local Windows 10 machine.  It starts up fine, I can connect to it with `hbase shell` and do puts, gets, scans and deletes no problem.  I'm very sure it is set up and working.

But connecting to it with Java has been a nightmare.  It now seems to be looking for kerberos, but I haven't specified kerberos anywhere in my config and I am NOT trying to use kerberos:

```
Failed to complete request: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: java.io.IOException: Call to myHostName/myBindAddress:16000 failed on local exception: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
```

Here's my setup in brief:

**hbase-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.master.port</name>
    <value>16000</value>
</property>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.master.info.bindAddress</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

**java code to connect from:**

```
    Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    // Have tried not adding the hbase-site.xml to config, seems to have no effect
    configuration.addResource(new Path(hbaseSiteXMLPath));
    // Manually specifying these just to be sure
    configuration.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase");
    configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
    configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration);

    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(configuration);
    Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(myTableName));

    Result result = table.get(get);
    table.close();
    connection.close();
```

It may be relevant to add that I'm using Spring Framework and I'm still learning it so there's a chance that some autoconfiguration is possibly happening in my pom.xml?  I'm posting it as well just in case its possible.

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- TESTING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HBASE & HADOOP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON Handlers -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Amazon AWS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.104</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SWAGGER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOGGING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SECURITY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>${jsoup.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DISCOVERY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DATA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SECURITY -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DATA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- FORMATTER AND REPORTS -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.plugin}</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.3</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                    <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
                <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>format</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <configFile>formatter.xml</configFile>
                            <lineEnding>LF</lineEnding>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/src/main/java/**/*.java</include>
                                <include>**/src/test/java/**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- MAVEN ENFORCER IS OPTIONAL - USED AS A SANITY CHECK -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <!--
                                <banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions/>
                                <dependencyConvergence/>
                                -->
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>[3.3.9,)</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>(1.8.0_212, )</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                                <requireSnapshotVersion>
                                    <message>No Snapshots Allowed!</message>
                                    <failWhenParentIsRelease>false</failWhenParentIsRelease>
                                </requireSnapshotVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.project.info.reports.plugin}</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>index</report>
                            <report>summary</report>
                            <report>scm</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.findbugs.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try some plain old **debugging** i.e. switching Log4J to `DEBUG` level, for your client app (and possibly for the Master service), and digging into these logs?

Comment: For the record, all Hadoop components (incl. HBase) scan their CLASSPATH to find directories _(and possibly JARs if someone was dumb enough to embed conf files in them)_ then scan these directories to find the implicit configuration files -- `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, `hbase-site.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding the following

```
    configuration.set("hbase.security.authentication", "simple");
    configuration.set("hbase.security.authorization", "false");
```

I don't know why the HBase API was defaulting to Kerberos but this was all I needed.